# Run sql in oracle multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I run a query or SQL script multiple times without explicitly pressing F9 from the keyboard?

Note : no PL/SQL code works on my system. I just have access as a DB client.

Comment: What do you mean?  It would be nice if you spent some time framing your question properly, so that people can understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: there is one sequence which has value < the max in the related table and difference is 400. So to improve that sequence I have to run the SELECT seq.nextval from dual 400 times to get to the maximum value. Can you pls advise how to inc. the value of sequence withour using alter command ?

Comment: "no pls/sql code works on my system. I just have access as DB client" - What client is that you are using? SQL*Plus?

Comment: Hi Ollie, it is TORA/sql developer

Comment: Why can't you use `alter` - just lack of permissions on the sequence? And is not being able to run even an anonymous PL/SQL block a restriction of TORA?

Comment: Are you using TORA or SQL Developer?  SQL Developer definitely has the ability to run anonymous PL/SQL blocks.  I'm hard-pressed to imagine that TORA doesn't have that ability as well.

Comment: According to the [website](http://torasql.com/about) it supports PL/SQL... (even has a debugger) so what does "as a DB client" mean? tora seems to be a DB client...

Answer (score 3):

Can't use DDL, can't use PL/SQL: if this isn't some exercise in database [OuLiPo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oulipo), it's a signifier of a dysfunctional organisation.  Really you should just talk to your DBA.

Anyway, here is a pure SQL way to increment a sequence by 400 clicks:

```
select your_seq.nextval
from dual
connect by level <= 400;
```